# how to delete session timed users in the mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have this table in the mqsql database

```
create table datedemo(logintime timestamp,updatedtime timestamp);
```

updatedtime  gives the last time the user was active  , i want execute a query

such that if the difference between the updatedtime and now() time is greater than some value say (1000 seconds)

below query gives the difference in timestamp , but i want to delete the rows , please help

```
SELECT NOW(), updatedtime, NOW() - updatedtime AS diff
FROM datedemo
HAVING diff IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Your query is a little nonsensical. `WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), updatedtime) > 1000` I would think would work. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM datedemo WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), updatedtime) > 1000
```

However, I think that it would be better to store expiration time not update time. I mean at update you insert not timestamp but TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, 1000, NOW()) . This way you do the math once and when it comes to checking you issue just:

```
DELETE FROM datedemo WHERE expirestime < NOW()
```

I think that it would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
SELECT NOW(), updatedtime
FROM datedemo
WHERE updatedtime > NOW() - INTERVAL 1000 Second
;
```